# How to stop windows 10 from automatically selecting new audio devices

Tags: windows-10, audio

Every time a new audio device is connected, Windows 10 selects the new device as its primary device.
Is there any way to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set default audio device for your windows computer?

Take windows 10 as example:

Control Panel--> Sound--> Choose the audio device that you prefer to be default

Note: Both options shall be changed because the latter one Set as default communications device matters when you make a video call or voice call through some appications, it will direct to the default communications device not the default playback device.

***Set as default device*** - All programs will have their audio played through this device (unless otherwise configured)

***Set as default communications device*** - All calls/video call audio will be played through this device (unless otherwise configured)

[image]

After change, it will be like:

[image]

Comment: Yes, windows will change the default as soon as a new device is connected

Comment: In my test, I preconfigured the Realtek Audio as both default devices and after then, even when I plugged in the new USB headset, it remains to be the default device without change.

I used to countered the issue like only pre-configured the audio for default device not communication device, then when I use communication apps like teams, it will choose the newly plugged in device as default when talking.